# wget - limit following to specific links

Tags: wget, web-crawler

I want to do mirror of website but limit following only to specific links.
Command:

```
wget --recursive --page-requisites --html-extension --convert-links --domains linuxmagazine.pl http://www.linuxmagazine.pl/index.php/magazine/archiwum
```

gives me entire page. I want to limit wget to "nr XX" links or URI */issues/*. Is it possible?